# How to change URL without load in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, location-href

I have a question **How to change URL without load**. I am working on a `PHP`, `JavaScript` project.
I am try to make without load Home page. in home Header section content some buttons like :-

[image: Header Button]

### Header

on click button than load data using `XMLHttpRequest()` and i want to change Url like:-

`https://example.com/home` to `https://example.com/search`

#### Code

```
var xmld = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmld.open("GET", "/Api/SearchPage", true);
    xmld.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmld.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmld.readyState == 4 && xmld.status == 200) {
            var json = JSON.parse(xmld.responseText);
            if (json.Status == "Ok") {
                doument.querySelector("#content").innerHTML = json.HTMLData;
                window.location.href = "https://exmaple.com/Search"; // without load
            }
        }
    }
    xmld.send();
```

*in example, when you click item than url change without load*

*I am not use any js and php framework*

### Example

> https://dribbble.com/

> https://in.pinterest.com/

it's possible??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/how-do-i-modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't use a framework `window.history.pushState()` will do the thing you want.
See this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState

Answer (score 0):

Use a state manager like Redux with a modern Javascript framework like ReactJs.

Comment: I would suggest Vue.js with [Vue-Router](https://router.vuejs.org/)